# Custom CSV Importer

Tags: 7, importing-exporting

I decided to write my own csv node importer since Feeds did not give me the functionality I needed. I have about 500 nodes to create each month and from that node it needs to create another node.

I have everything working right for a few nodes, however for 500 I get a 'page not found'. I want to echo out 'Node $nodeID created' so the users knows the script is working. I tried ob_start but I can't seem to get it to keep echoing out the result.

Does anyone have a better solution?

Here is a simple snippet:

```
 $file_handle = fopen("FinalListToIMport.csv", "r");
  ob_start();

 $i = 0;
  while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $row = fgetcsv($file_handle, 100024);
    if($i != 0 && $row[0] != ''){
        $update_node = node_load($nid);
        $update_node->title = 'update title';
        node_save($update_node);
       echo('Node: '.$row[0].'updated');
    ob_flush();


    }
$i++;
 }

 fclose($file_handle);
```

Comment: could you post the code?

Comment: Here is a simple snippet:

Comment: forgot the code i guess...

Comment: Just added it to the regular post, sorry

Comment: could paste the one with ob_start that did not work for you...

Comment: Ok, I re added it. I'm trying to just keep the simple part. I just want to see it keep out putting on the screen, thanks!

Comment: I added the module and enable batch api, is there somewhere I need to go in the backend?

Comment: that is an example module which you can check and see how the batching is done in drupal you should study the code and will get an idea about how the process works.

Comment: Thanks for the help, do you know if this can be ran from a bootstrap?

Comment: there is an example in this link but that is for 6 so there might be some changes. http://www.stonemind.net/blog/2009/01/20/headless-drupal-using-drupals-api-to-batch-script-your-drupal-site/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that is actually using the batchAPI?

Comment: no that is just using the bootstarp of drupal and then pure php form there on with node update and adding through drupal APIs put batch API as in the example module is the way to go forward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [drupal_set_message()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_set_message/7) to send a feedback to the user. It's the best way to do that in my opinion.

**EDITED**

In order to prevent the timeout issue you must use [Drupal's Batch API](http://drupal.org/node/180528).

Here goes another example: https://gist.github.com/4329270

Comment: Drupal Set message might not be the way to go as the script is exceeding the execution time and hence the page not found error.

Comment: I totally agree with the batch process. But he still should use Drupal's API to send the message.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted but revagomes has my upvote :)
also, @Brian, make sure that you check that the node actually exists before you call node_save(). and a tip: you can load multiple nodes using node_load_multiple().

Answer (score 2):

Since this is running a long script I would suggest looking at the [example](http://drupal.org/project/examples) module.

There is a module with in that called batch_example

That explains how you can put a progress bar or in your case the node id as the script progress.

Answer (score 1):

I did this while back just as Shameem suggested, custom code using Batching so there would not be any memory problems.

Alternatively you could try going back to Feeds and use module Feeds Tamper http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper which lets you alter the data a bit on the way in.

Comment: I did use feeds however I needed a cck field set as my unique target and it would not let me. I would love to use feeds again if I could figure out how to flag that field as unique.